# Using a manual function in scale_continuous ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code works perfectly without scale_y_continuous geom.
Why does this code return an error when I try to use a manual function in scale_y_continuous geom:

```
library('tibble')
library("ggplot2")

df <- tibble(x=c(1:5),
        y=c(11:15))

MyFunction <- function(x){
 if(x>12){
   return(paste0('$', x))
 }else{
   return(paste0('&', x))
 }
}

ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+
geom_line()+
scale_y_continuous(
 labels = function(x) MyFunction(x)
)
```

Error text:

```
 Warning message:
 In if (x > 12) { :
 the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: try `MyFunction <- function(x) {ifelse(x > 12, paste0('$', x), paste0('&', x))}`. The if else logic isn't vectorised as you have it now.

Comment: @teunbrand actually yes. Is there another way to fix it?

Comment: my real Myfunction is much longer

Comment: It's kind of hard to fix a bug in a function without seeing the actual code for it.

Comment: no, the code of the function is OK, the problem only when I try to use it in scale_y_continuous. I understand that I have to vectorise it. It works. But is there another way?

Comment: Have you tried `scale_y_continuous(label = MyFunction)`? If that doesn't work, I'm going to suggest that is is your function that isn't working as expected. Can you verify that your function returns a vector of the same length as the input?